# Double data type giving garbage value as output after taking input through scanf()

Tags: c, double, scanf

```c
main()
{   
    double B_Sal, DR_Al,H_RA, Total_Sal;
    printf("Enter Your Basic Salary ");
    scanf("%f",&B_Sal);
    printf("the amount entered is %f \n",B_Sal);
    DR_Al=0.4*B_Sal;
    H_RA=0.2* B_Sal;
    Total_Sal=B_Sal+ DR_Al+ H_RA;
    printf("The Total Salary Is %f",Total_Sal);
    
}
```

Whatever input is given it just gives output as ***negative garbage value***. This same code when data type is change to ***float*** works fine.

Comment: The compiler should be warning you about the incorrect format specifier in `scanf("%f",&B_Sal);` which should be `%lf`. If it didn't, turn on full warnings, and if it still didn't, get a better compiler. It is `%f` for `float` and `%lf` for `double`. Don't compare this with the way `printf` behaves: it's a function with a few similarities but actually quite different.

Comment: Ohh thanks it worked... I am a beginner though.

Comment: So are we all.. `scanf` is given to beginners to use, but it isn't at all easy.

Answer (score 2):

To get double as input the specifier is %lf,

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    double B_Sal, DR_Al,H_RA, Total_Sal;
    printf("Enter Your Basic Salary ");
    scanf("%lf",&B_Sal);
    printf("the amount entered is %f \n",B_Sal);
    DR_Al=0.4*B_Sal;
    H_RA=0.2* B_Sal;
    Total_Sal=B_Sal+ DR_Al+ H_RA;
    printf("The Total Salary Is %f",Total_Sal);
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of plain text. Instead copy&paste it as formatted text directly into your question. That applies for code as well as for text input and output of the program.

Comment: @Gerhardh - It is common, and reasonable to use screen shots of example outputs to demonstrate the _exact_ representation of the response resulting from the answer code.  The reason for not including it into questions is that it makes it difficult for potential attempts to help because images cannot be compiled :)

Comment: @ryyker I would agree if there was anything special regarding formatting, weird characters etc. that can not be represented as plain text. Nothing of that applies to that example. Also there is no reason to include extra printouts that don't come from the program but from the IDE.